# BLOB to String or image / PHP or sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've an array that gives me an image blob in the 3rd dimension.

but I need the image, i tried with SQL

```
<?php $global = \Database::getInstance()->execute('SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(40), image)
    FROM mm_product2 
    WHERE id = '.$referenzen['id'])->fetchAllAssoc(); ?>
<?php print_r($global);?>
```

It show this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception Exception with message Query error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VarChar(40),
image) FROM mm_product2 WHERE id = 23' at line 1 (SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(40), 
image) FROM mm_product2 WHERE id = 23
```

without the expressions it works but i get that blob value again like in the standard array:

```
[image] => 85392c33-a0f7-11e4-acb9-08606e695836 )
```

May I know how to convert that value in PHP or only in SQL ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use mysql query to get the blob data in a variable and then use this

```
'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" width="200" height="200">'
```

Comment: my cms dont allow me to querry and i dont want to type in database information in this template. any other ideas ?

Comment: just replace $image of my code with your $global and remove convert statement

Comment: <?php $global = \Database::getInstance()->execute('SELECT  image
    FROM mm_product2 
    WHERE id = '.$referenzen['id'])->fetchAllAssoc(); ?>
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($global) . '" width="200" height="200">';

Comment: looks good, i only get that error for now: base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. but ill work around tomorrow =) hopefully i can make a string from that. Thank you all !!!

Comment: @mike please mark it useful if this ans show u sme path

Comment: sry i cant because ive a too low reputation